# Access Firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a project with Firebase. I want to have access to the attribute "text" of my database with a cloud function as soon as there is a recent branch added to my database.

I am not get used to using their database.

[image]

My code in NodeJs is bellow :

```
    exports.messageAnswer = functions.database.ref('/messages')
    .onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const val = snapshot.val();
    var textMsg = val.text;
    var regex = "(bot)";
    //var database = firebase.database();
    if(!textMsg.match(regex) && textMsg.length > 0){
        var id = new Date().getTime().toString();       
        var object = {
            text : "I am the Cloud bot #" + id,
        };
        admin.database().ref('/messages').push(object);
    }

        return 0;
    });
```

My problem is the fact that there is a "PUSH ID" : I don't know how to contourne this unique string to get the value of the attribute "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wildcards` to get the `text` attribute some something like this:

```
 exports.messageAnswer = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushid}')
.onWrite(event => {
```

for more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions

> You can specify a path component as a wildcard by surrounding it with curly brackets; ref('foo/{bar}') matches any child of /foo. The values of these wildcard path components are available within the event.params object of your function. In this example, the value is available as event.params.bar

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is being triggered whenever any data under `/messages` changes. From your description it seems you only want to be triggered when a new message is added. You do that by using `onCreate` instead of `onWrite`. In addition you'll want to listen for changes to a specific message, instead of to the entire `/messages` node:

```
exports.messageAnswer = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}')
.onCreate(event => {
```

Also see Doug's blog post on these triggers: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/cloud-functions-realtime-database.html